# Azure Media Services DRM Integration With 3rd Party Unified Streaming Server

Tags: azure, drm, azure-media-services, exoplayer

Overview

We are building a music streaming application that will be primarily targeted at Android devices. The main aim is to sell music subscriptions while protecting the media assets we are providing our end-users, thus A DRM solution is core to our infrastructure. The setup we have is as below:

Core Components:

1. Android Mobile Application with Exoplayer
2. Unified Streaming Server as streaming server
3. Azure Media Services for DRM services
4. Key generation utilities from Azure Media Services Sdk

These are the steps we take:

Step 1: Encoding

We use ffmpeg to encode our various media assets to different mp4 bit rate outputs:

- 256 KBPS
- 192 KBPS
- 128 KBPS
- 96 KBPS
- 64 KBPS

Step 2: Encryption
Once we have converted our media assets, we run a two-step encoding process on the converted media assets.

- First, we run the AZURE .NET SDK for key generation with the following sample output:

> key:nb:kid:UUID:fae1ab22-cd13-44f8-a746-0d7dd3a31645
>
> key value:MVEp833L3jmUaNvTy3JUuQ==
>
> PlayReady URL:
>   https://music.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net/PlayReady/
>
> Widevine URL:
>   https://music.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net/Widevine/?KID=fae1ab22-cd13-44f8-a746-0d7dd3a31645
>
> Auth policy: nb:ckpid:UUID:15ec2f3f-4ad9-49be-9f89-b5431bc3dec1

That generates for us the following items: KEY_ID, CONTENT_KEY,AUTH_POLICY and LICENSE_URL.

We have noted when using the Azure .NET SDK that there is a token restriction policy option which is responsible for generating token protection for licenses via SWT or JWT tokens with a bunch of options. Since we do not want token protection, we set the SDK to issue the license with open authorization policy. We have highlighted the lines of code we modified to achieve this below for reference:

[Azure Media Services .NET SDK](https://github.com/Azure/media-services-dotnet-deliver-drm-licenses)

```
Line 49:
      bool tokenRestriction = false; - main change

    Line 81:
      if (tokenRestriction)
        tokenTemplateString = AddTokenRestrictedAuthorizationPolicy(key);
      else
        AddOpenAuthorizationPolicy(key);
      Console.WriteLine("Auth policy: {0}",
      key.AuthorizationPolicyId,          System.Convert.ToBase64String(key.GetClearKeyValue()));
```

Since ExoPlayer is only able to play PlayReady on Android TV, we are restricted to requesting Widevine licences.

- We then use the Unified Streaming mp4split tool to encrypt our media assets with the information we highlighted above from the Azure .NET SDK. The command to encrypt assets for Widevine licences is shown below with more details on the command here.

Notes on the command:

We need to convert our KEY_ID and CONTENT_KEY to hexadecimal values before we can use them in the mp4split command:

> KEY_ID of UUID:fae1ab22-cd13-44f8-a746-0d7dd3a31645   becomes
>   22ABE1FA13CDF844A7460D7DD3A31645
>
> CONTENT_KEY of MVEp833L3jmUaNvTy3JUuQ==   becomes
>   315129F37DCBDE399468DBD3CB7254B9

We still don't know what the PSSH value is from the response we get from the Azure .NET SDK. The Unified Streaming documentation says the following:

The DRM specific data provided by the license server (the Widevine PSSH data).
Can either be a Base64 string or a file with the decoded Base64 data. The file name must include a '.'

Note that the LA_URL (license acquisition URL) is not signaled in the "pssh" box and is often hard-coded in a DASH player supporting Winevine Modular itself. The recommended setting is to use the correct URL.

We are looking for assistance in figuring out what the PSSH Data is from the Azure .NET SDK output that we receive. In the meantime we have been using the AUTH_POLICY_ID (converted to Base64) as the PSSH in the mp4split command.

When we put all the above together, the mp4split script we use becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
      KID=22ABE1FA13CDF844A7460D7DD3A31645
      CEK=315129F37DCBDE399468DBD3CB7254B9
      LAURL="https://music.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net/Widevine/?     KID=fae1ab22-cd13-44f8-a746-0d7dd3a31645"
      PSSH="Py/sFdlKvkmfibVDG8PewQ=="

      mp4split --license-key=usp/license.key -o musicfile.ism \
        --mpd.inline_drm \
        --widevine.key=${KID}:${CEK} \
        --widevine.license_server_url=${LAURL} \
        --widevine.drm_specific_data=${PSSH} \
        musicfile-64kbps.mp4

      aws s3 cp musicfiles.ism s3://output-bucket/
      aws s3 cp musicfiles-64kbps.mp4 s3://output-bucket/
```

NOTES:

1. For the above command we are generating an ism manifest file with Widevine licence encryption for a 64kps bitrate mp4 music file.
2. The --license-key is for the unified streaming premium product.
3. The AWS S3 commands are for uploading our generated ism and associated mp4 64kps bitrate file to our aws s3 storage buckets.

Once this process is done, the next step is integration with ExoPlayer.

Step 3: Streaming

Once we upload our .ism and its associated mp4 file to our S3 bucket, the mobile app uses the following details to access the stream and play it back:

```
{
        "name": "Music Tests",
        "uri": "http://mozart.musicfiles.com/auth/media/musicfiles.ism/.mpd",
        "drm_scheme": "widevine",
        "drm_license_url":      "https://music.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net/Widevine/?KID=fae1ab22-cd13-44f8-a746-0d7dd3a31645"
      }
```

Where:

URI - is our Unified Streaming server endpoint
DRM_LICENSE_URI -  is widevine server url we are given by our Azure .NET SDK

We get errors at this stage after we have uploaded, encoded and encrypted the media assets. The error in the Android app is the following:

```
02-07 12:58:58.458 16454-5913/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo   E/OMXMaster: A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists,  ignoring this one.
    02-07 12:59:02.892 16454-5811/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.shouldWaitForKeys(MediaCodecRenderer.java:709)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:650)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:490)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:464)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:300)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
    Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onError(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:594)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onKeysError(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:589)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onKeyResponse(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:549)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.access$900(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:49)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager$PostResponseHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:669)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40) 
    Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:212)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:81)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:75)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:118)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executePost(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:106)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executeKeyRequest(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:91)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager$PostRequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:692)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    02-07 12:59:02.896 16454-16454/com.google.android.exoplayer2.demo E/EventLogger: playerFailed [7.76]
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.shouldWaitForKeys(MediaCodecRenderer.java:709)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:650)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:490)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:464)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:300)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
    Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onError(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:594)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onKeysError(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:589)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.onKeyResponse(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:549)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager.access$900(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:49)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager$PostResponseHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:669)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40) 
    Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:212)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:81)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:75)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:118)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executePost(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:106)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executeKeyRequest(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:91)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSessionManager$PostRequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSessionManager.java:692)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The Error Codes from the Azure Media Services here states the following for response code 400:

[Azure Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-error-codes)

> 400 Bad Request   The request contains invalid information and is
>   rejected due to one of the following reasons:
>
> -An unsupported API version is specified. For the most current
>   version, see Setup for Media Services REST API Development.   -The API
>   version of Media Services is not specified. For information on how to
>   specify the API version, see Connecting to Media Services with the
>   Media Services REST API.   Note
>
> If you are using the .NET or Java SDKs to connect to Media Services,
>   the API version is specified for you whenever you try and perform some
>   action against Media Services.
>
> - An undefined property has been specified. The property name is in the error message. Only those properties that are members of a given
>     entity can be specified. See Azure Media Services REST API Reference
>     for a list of entities and their properties.
>
>   - An invalid property value has been specified. The property name is in the error message. See the previous link for valid property types
>       and their values.
> - A property value is missing and is required.
>
>   - Part of the URL specified contains a bad value.
> - An attempt was made to update a WriteOnce property.
> - An attempt was made to create a Job that has an input Asset with a primary AssetFile that was not specified or could not be determined.
> - An attempt was made to update a SAS Locator. SAS locators can only be created or deleted. Streaming locators can be updated. For more
>     information, see Locators.
>
>   - An unsupported operation or query was submitted.

Also in addition to that when we run a GET Request on the widevine server url

```
GET https://music.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net/Widevine/?KID=fae1ab22-cd13-44f8-a746-0d7dd3a31645
```

We get the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
<Message>License challenge is missing from the request body.</Message>
<Code>NoLicenseChallenge</Code>
</Error>
```

What does the above error message mean?

We have been reading the Azure Documentation but we have not been able to figure out how to resolve the error.

We are trying to integrate our third party streaming server unified streaming with azure media services DRM solution.

Comment: In fact what ExoPlayer ought to do when calling the license acquisition URL (https://music.keydelivery.mediaservices.windows.net/Widevine/?KID=....) is to perform an HTTP POST containing a "challenge". That's why you get that error message when you do a "manual" GET.

If you do a network trace on what ExoPlayer is actually sending to that server, what do you see?